# AVPlayer status: message was received but not handled

Tags: xcode, swift, avplayer, addobserver

I'm pretty new to observers and Swift/ObjC, and I'm trying to monitor AVPlayer status using one as said in Apple's documentation, but everything I get is a **"message was received but not handled"** error message when I try to add the observer.

```
gs_mediaObjAdv=AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: mediaURL));
gs_mediaObjAdv.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context:nil);
```

If I unregister the observer, the error disappear but if I add a *println("test")* inside the **observeValueForKeyPath** function, nothing happens.

Any idea in how can I monitor the status in a simple way?

Comment: what is your `observeValueForKeyPath` code

Comment: have you made a super call such as `[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];` ? I think the issue might exist if your super isn't KVO compliant. Try commenting the code.

Comment: did you got the solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

Please check for the Observer method which you have an override.
It has to be an instance method instead of a class method.

Comment: that was exactly my issue :

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for whoever else needs it
Swift 5.1

```
//playerViewController is defined as a class member 
//let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
self.playerViewController.player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        if let rate = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? Float {
            if rate == 0.0 {
                print("playback stopped")
                //view.addSubview(drawView)
            }
            if rate == 1.0 {
                print("normal playback")
            }
            if rate == -1.0 {
                print("reverse playback")
            }
        }
    }
    super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
}
```